# I can't install steam installer on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: steam

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  steam:i386 : Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed

> > ```
> >          Depends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
> >          Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 17.3) but it is not going to be installed or
> >                 libtxc-dxtn0:i386 but it is not installable
> >          Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
> >          Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
> >          Recommends: libxss1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
> >          Recommends: nvidia-driver-libs-i386:i386 but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> > ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)